# MacOS Text substitutions not working on Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox

I use the text substitutions on MacOs a lot, to type a shorcut and then the system completes a full word or sentences. For instance, if i type 'hel', MacOs will substitue to 'Hello, how can i help you ?'.

This works great in Chrome, but for some reason, does not work in Firefox. As much as i like Firefox, without this feature i can't leave Chrome.

Is there any setting to make it work on Firefox ?

Comment: It requires that the app supports the Mac Toolbox guidelines. I'm quite surprised Chrome follows it on this - it usually doesn't for many things. I can confirm Firefox doesn't. Report it as a bug, see if they're interested in fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is no setting to make this work. There is a bug report for this which is 9 years old: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1149826

Comment: Bad for Firefox, a lot of people (incluiding me) don't use it because this failure

Comment: I don't want to switch away from FF. For now, I open Spotlight, type the short version of the text replacement, copy the expanded text, and paste the text.